# MySQL query enclosing numbers in strings

Tags: mysql, casting

Suppose I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x > y;
```

where "y" is a user-input value. I'd like to enclose y in quotes. So far as I've tested, the query works properly when the quotes are added. Is the behaviour defined? Is it known to result in an efficiency drop?

Note that the query is an example fabricated for simplicity. Also, this is not an attempt to deal with SQL injection.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: Is the behaviour defined, and is it known to result in an efficiency drop?

Comment: Enclosing values in quotes isn't what protects against injection.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not trying to protect against injection. It was just a simple way to frame the question.

Comment: Why did you mention injection at all?

Comment: Because I find that people, when presented with an abstract question, tend to suggest alternative methods of achieving what they think you want, or questioning your reasoning, rather than answering your question. I appreciate that they're trying to be helpful but more often than not they lack sufficient information to provide useful alternatives.

Comment: @wyatt: sometimes the alternate method is the proper answer, especially as most questions are about issues with a [specific solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) rather than about solving the [original problem](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal) (the XY problem), and the attempted solution may go about things the wrong way. As for people having to guess at your overall goal, you can cut down on this by providing the missing information: describe the overall goal. Throwing in a red herring like injection just confuses matters.

Comment: @outis I'm sorry, that comment was giving me pause, starting to sound a little trollish. I do think the concern is valid, but I suppose you're right in that manipulating the answer I want isn't the greatest of solutions.

Comment: @wyatt: no need for apologies. I just didn't want you to derail your own question. Bringing up injection was a bit like saying "I'm not a kleptomaniac" when introducing yourself–people make assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the field that you are trying to compare with is a numeric field ie `int`, then all the possible combinations must work in mysql

```
select * from users where id = 20;

select * from users where id = "20";

select * from users where id = '20';
```

Refer the [MySQL DOC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) for more depth

Answer (score 0):

The [conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html) behavior of MySQL when comparing different types is well-defined. When a string and a number are compared, both are converted to floats. It's outlined in the manual, § 11.2.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, you can try :-

```
cast( "-10" as signed )
```

This is casting in mysql (the function name is cast, obvious?).

Comment: -2 is fine, but I really eager to know what's wrong with the above?

Comment: There are a couple of drive-by downvotes for this question. If I had to guess, it's because this answer doesn't address the questions. Specifically, Wyatt was asking whether the behavior he was seeing was specified anywhere, rather than how he could ensure a value was of a certain type. Or perhaps the cast isn't necessary, since comparing a number with a string will result in a floating point comparison.

Comment: well, if the down-voters is really reading the docs, he will be surprise the quoting a variable is no diff from casting, and the proper casting to the column type is the measurement for this question. sorry, for being arrogant, this is how i see the natural of casting does.

Comment: I don't see it as arrogant. Not sure what you mean by "measurement for this question".

Comment: define in this docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html), numerous mention casting is the proper solution instead of quote the string (of course in that doc, there are more examples and indepth explanation)

Comment: Wyatt isn't asking for the solution to anything; indeed, he hasn't described the problem that he's trying to solve by putting a value in quotes (the question thus suffers from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)). This, in part, makes your answer off-topic. If you mean to say Wyatt has turned down the wrong path and you're offering a better solution, you should explicitly say so; this is the other missing piece that makes your answer off-topic.

Comment: Still not seeing what you mean by "measurement", which generally means quantifying something by applying a standard rule or measure, or applying a metric.